# find exec and strip extension from filenames

Tags: bash, find

Any idea why this command is not working? btw, I'm trying to strip out the extensions of all csv files in current directory.

```
find -type f -iname "*.csv" -exec mv {} $(basename {} ".csv") \;
```

Tried many variants including the parameter expansions, xargs ... Even then all went futile.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do:

```sh
 find ./ -type f -iname "*.csv" -exec sh -c 'mv {} $(basename {} .csv)' \;
```

`find` is able to substitute `{}` with its findings since the quotes prevent executing the subshell until `find` is done. Then it executes the `-exec` part.

---

The problem why yours is not working is that `$(basename {} ".csv")` is executed in a subshell (-> `$()`) **and evaluated beforehand**. If we look at the command execution step-by-step you will see what happens:

1. `find -type f -iname "*.csv" -exec mv {} $(basename {} ".csv") \;` - your command
2. `find -type f -iname "*.csv" -exec mv {} {} \;` - subshell gets evaluated (`$(basename {} ".csv")` returns `{}` since it interprets `{}` as a literal)
3. `find -type f -iname "*.csv" -exec mv {} {} \;` - as you see now: move does actually nothing

Comment: FYI embedding `{}` will fail if any files contain whitespace or other special characters. This can be fixed with `-exec sh -c 'mv "$1" $(basename "$1" .csv)' sh {} \;` so that `sh` receives the files as an argument, `$1`. The extra `sh` at the end is to set `$0` to `sh` like it would normally be set to.

Comment: @JohnKugelman > "like it would normally be set to". Could you expand why that matters when we are invoking `sh` by `-exec` and utilizing `$1`?

Comment: @Ari It matches what `$0` would be set to during a normal invocation of `sh`. That way you get the same error messages as normal, e.g. `sh: mvv: command not found` if you misspelt `mv`, since they're prefixed with `"$0: "`.

Answer (score 2):

First, take care that you have no subdirectories; `find`, without extra arguments, will automatically recur into any directory below.

Simple approach: if you have a small enough number of files, just use the glob (*) operator, and take advantage of [rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html):

```
$ rename 's/.csv$//' *.csv
```

If you have too many files, use `find`, and perhaps `xargs`:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.csv" | xargs rename 's/.csv$//'
```

If you want to be *really* safe, tell `find` and `xargs` to delimit with null-bytes, so that you don't have weird filenames (e.g., with spaces or newlines) mess up the process:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.csv" -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/.csv$//'
```